# Linear transformation *not* to use to scale mean and SD

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-transformation, linear

I'm working through the Exercises in [Regression and Other Stories](https://avehtari.github.io/ROS-Examples/).

Exercise 3.6 on *Linear transformations* asks you to provide a formula to rescale a variable with mean = 35 and SD = 10 to have mean = 100 and SD = 15.

This is straight forward:

```
y = 47.5 + 1.5 * x
```

The next exercise then asks: "there is another transformation that rescales the scores to have mean = 100 and SD = 15. What is it and why would you *not* want to use it for this purpose."

I can't work out what is being referred to here?

Comment: Hint: what is the SD of $-1.5\,x$?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to whuber for the hint that broke my mental block on this one.

The transformation to avoid would be

```
y <- 152.5 - 1.5 * x
```

This is a bad idea because it means x and y are negatively correlated. The example refers to test scores, so this would obviously be a bad way to rescale them!

Comment: +1 Sometimes, though, this kind of rescoring is helpful.  For instance, when administering a questionnaire, you might expect high answers on some questions to correspond to low answers on others, depending on whether they have been positively or negatively framed.  This kind of direction-reversing re-expression can produce data with consistent meaning and afford consistent interpretations of positive and negative correlations.